# Where do the unnamed pilot and "The Enchanted Parade" fall chronologically in "Little Witch Academia"?

Tags: little-witch-academia

"Little Witch Academia" started at first as a one-off project, then a second single film "The Enchanted Parade" was released after being funded via Kickstarter.

Recently Netflix released a series based on these two projects. Based on the first and last episodes, it's clear the unnamed pilot and "The Enchanted Parade" must have happened between the two, but where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TV show is a complete reboot. That is why in the show Diana is not outright mean to Akko, while in the short and movie she is. Also Akko cannot ride a broom at all in the show while in the short and movie she is just bad at it. They revamped the story to be able to do more with it, making Akko an ordinary human instead of just a bad witch.